# copying files between s3 buckets without folders amazon aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm looking through the documentation of aws cli and I cannot find the way to copy the only files in some directory structure to other bucket with "flattened" structure(I want one directory and all files inside of it).

for example

```
/a/b/c/1.pg
/a/2.jpg
/a/b/3.jpg
```

i would want to have in different bucket:

```
/x/1.jpg
/x/2.jpg
/x/3.jpg
```

Am I missing something or is it impossible?
Do you have an idea how could I do that?

Comment: What about files with similar names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download files locally, as suggested in another answer. Instead, you could write a shell script or something that does the following:

- Run [ls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) on `s3://bucket1` to get fully-qualified names of all files in it.
- For each file, run [cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) to copy it from current location to `s3://bucket2/x/`

Comment: I had to go with this one

Comment: Sure, if you know how to write a shell script..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have aws cli configured on the system and assuming that both the buckets are in the same region.
What you can do is first dowload the s3 bucket to your local machine using:

```
aws s3 sync s3://originbucket /localdir/
```

Post this, use a find command to get all the files into one dir

```
find /localdir/ -type f -exec mv {} /anotherlocaldir/
```

Finally, you can upload the files to s3 again!

```
aws s3 sync /anotherlocaldir/ s3://destinationbucket
```

Comment: I don't think s3 will allow it for various reasons, what if you had 1.jpg under different directory structures? which file would it consider then!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$foo = aws s3 ls s3://blah/blah --recursive | Select-String -Pattern "somePattern" | ConvertFrom-String

$foo | % { 
  $f = $_.P4
  $fileToCopy = "s3://blah/$f"
  $fileToCopy
  aws s3 cp $fileToCopy .
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some examples for your reference:

aws s3 sync /a/b/c/1.pg s3://bucketname/

aws s3 sync /a/2.jpg s3://bucketname/

aws s3 sync /a/b/3.jpg s3://bucketname/

To sync all contents of a dir to S3 bucket:

aws s3 sync /directoryPath/ s3://bucketname/

AWS reference url: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html